# Customizing and overriding some functions of a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need to customize a Wordpress plugin so as to fit our local needs. I've actually changed some files from the plugin itself to fulfill the local needs, and they work like a charm. But as you all know, its definitely not a good practice, since the moment the main plugin is updated, the modified files will get overwritten, and then everything is gone.
I actually want to create a new plugin and inside it I want to tell Wordpress that whenever a certain function is called, just don't do it and do another function as I determine it for Wordpress. See the following code, please:

```
function access_from( $id, $user_id, $product_id) {
   ...   
         local_visible = Br::turn_gregorian_timestamp_to_local($visible_since);
         $current_time = Br::get_local_timestamp();
         if ( $current_time < $local_visible ) {
            $return = apply_filters('product_access_from__visibility_since', $local_visible, $product_id, $user_id );
         }
      }
   }
```

This is not the whole code. This is only a part of it. I have just brought the parts that I need to modify so that the plugin's date and time will suit us. So here is the scenario: How should I tell Wordpress to call a specific function whenever another function is called and does it the way I determine. So that I will be able to modify some parts of plugin related to date and time. In our case, we are going to actually tell Wordpress that whenever the function **access_from** is called, just take its values, and put them in my modified access_from function, for example called **new_access_from**.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the original function have action/hook (add_filter()) that you can trigger from the theme's functions.php file?

If the function is accessible through hooks, you could do something like (I think):
`add_filter('access_from','givemesomecustomfunction',$priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1);`

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

**Concerning you question on how to trigger:**
The best way I can think how to edit this is using  **add_filter** to rewrite the complete function of the plugin.